# Proof that $\frac{(x+y)-abs(x-y)}{2}$ equivalent to $\min(x,y)$

Tags: functions, proof-writing

I plotted the two functions $\frac{(x+y)-abs(x-y)}{2}$ and $min(x,y)$ in the range $[-1, 1]$ and they look the same. The both $min$ and $abs$ functions are defined as expected.

$abs(x)=\begin{cases}&x,&0<x,\\-&x,&\text{else.}\end{cases}$

$\min(x,y)=\begin{cases}x,&x<y,\\y,&\text{else.}\end{cases}$

[image: plot of min function in range -1 to 1]

The $min$ function is quite easy to imagine. For the other function, I think of it as the average of $x$ and $y$ minus their half distance. Anyhow, I haven't an imagination of both functions being equal yet. Could you provide a proof and the idea behind it to me?

Comment: Just consider two cases separately: When $x\le y$, and when $y\le x$. Simplify both expressions in each case, and you're done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof is simple -- just consider the two possible cases:

- If $x\geq y$, the absolute value is equal to plain $(x-y)$ and $\min(x,y)=y$ and left-hand side is equal to the right-hand side.
- If $x<y$, the absolute value is equal to $(y-x)$ and $\min(x,y)=x$. Again, LHS = RHS.

Since these are the only possible cases, the proof is complete.

The intuition behind it is exactly as you described it -- $\frac{x+y}{2}$ is exactly halfway between $x$ and $y$, so if we move this half-distance "down" (= towards smaller numbers), we'll reach the smaller of the two numbers. If we added $|x-y|$ instead of subtracting it, we'd get $\max(x,y)$.

Comment: Thanks, so the one is just branch less notation for the other. Just for curiosity, can one write any function that uses cases without using them?

Comment: This depends on the condition in the cases. If it is just inequality of two expressions, the answer is yes (although the form with cases might actually be considerably easier to grasp).

Comment: As far as being branch-less goes, it's just disguised -- after all, $\abs(x)$ is also defined using branches.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, I think we could define $abs(x)$ as $sqrt(x^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $-|x| = \min\{-x, x\}$.

We want to relate $\min\{x, y\}$ to $|x|$. We'll use the fact that for any $a$ we have $$\min\{x, y\} = \min\{x - a, y - a\} + a.$$ If $x - a$ and $y - a$ were negatives of one another, we would be able to replace $\min\{x - a, y - a\}$ by $-|x - a|$ (which would also be equal to $-|y-a|$). So the question becomes, can we choose $a$ such that $x - a = -(y - a)$? The answer is yes. Rearranging this equation we get $a = \frac{1}{2}(x+y)$. Therefore we have

\begin{align*}
\min\{x, y\} &= \min\{x - a, y -a\} + a\\ 
&= \min\left\{x - \frac{1}{2}(x+y), y - \frac{1}{2}(x+y)\right\} + \frac{1}{2}(x+y)\\
&= \min\left\{\frac{1}{2}(y-x), \frac{1}{2}(x - y)\right\} + \frac{1}{2}(x+y)\\
&= \min\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(x-y), \frac{1}{2}(x-y)\right\} + \frac{1}{2}(x+y)\\
&= -\left|\frac{1}{2}(x-y)\right| + \frac{1}{2}(x+y)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}(x+y-|x+y|).
\end{align*}

If you think about $x$ and $y$ on the numberline, what we've done is found the midpoint of $x$ and $y$ which is the unique point which is equidistant to $x$ and $y$. By substracting this value, we shift $x$ and $y$ to opposite sides of zero, but we have preserved distances. That is, the point that $x$ gets sent to has the same distance to zero as the point that $y$ gets sent to. Therefore they are negatives of one another (if they are not equal), so the question of which is smaller can now be calculated using the absolute value.

Comment: +1 for using (an equivalent of) $\;\left| x \right| = x \text{ max } {-x}\;$.

Answer (score 1):

$
\renewcommand{\max}{\mathrel{\rm max}}
\renewcommand{\min}{\mathrel{\rm min}}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left| #1 \right|}
$The simplest way I see to prove this is to first use
$$
\abs x = x \max -x
$$
and then use the properties of $\;\max\;$ (and $\;\min\;$).

We start at the most complex side, $\;\frac{x+y-\abs{x-y}}{2}\;$, or rather (to avoid many divisions by 2) we start with its numerator, and calculate as follows:

\begin{align}
& x + y - \left| x - y \right| \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"express $\;\left| \cdot \right|\;$ in terms of $\;\max\;$"} \\
& x + y - ((x - y) \max (y - x)) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"the negation of $\;\max\;$ is $\;\min\;$, with the arguments negated"} \\
& x + y + ((y - x) \min (x - y)) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"$\;+\;$ distributes over $\;\min\;$"} \\
& (x + y + y - x) \min (x + y + x - y) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"simplify"} \\
& (2 \times y) \min (2 \times x) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"$\;z \times\;$ distributes over $\;\min\;$, for $\;z \ge 0\;$"} \\
& 2 \times (y \min x) \\
\end{align}
After division by 2 and using the symmetry of $\;\min\;$, this proves the required $\;\frac{x+y-\abs{x-y}}{2} = x \min y\;$.

Comment: I have never seen $\min$ and $\max$ placed between two arguments. Is there a reason you prefer $x \min y$ to $\min\{x, y\}$?

Comment: Yes. Originally I learned this from Dijkstra et al., see [EWD1300](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1300.html) under "Infix notation and expressions". The main reason is that $\;\text{max}\;$ is associative; this saves parentheses.  Perhaps more importantly, it gives consistency of notation between $\;x \le x\text{ max } y\;$, $\;P \Rightarrow P \lor Q\;$, $\;a \mid a * b\;$, $\;A \subseteq A \cup B\;$, etc. which all obey the same laws from lattice theory.  Also (as Dijkstra) personally I prefer to write $\;\uparrow\;$, but on MSE I avoid that for clarity.